# How do I Search for text on a website using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I want to create a `VBScript` that looks for a given word combination on a web page.
If the script found the same text, type: hits -with echo.

I found a solution [here](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1700446) that is partly what I want, but so far I haven't been able to convert it so that the script does what I want.
Could you help me with how to transform it to work. Or is there a better solution?
I'm a beginner in `VbScripts` and I want to do it in this because there is already a system that has been done with vbscript and I want to incorporate this feature.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: and I find this solution more: https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/web/general/examples/checking-specific-text.html but here:    Browsers.Item(btIExplorer).Run url                                                                                       - stops with an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that : Using `InternetExplorer.Application` Object

```
Option Explicit
Call Find("StackOverflow","https://stackoverflow.com")
Call Find("google","https://www.google.com")
Call Find("yahoo","https://www.yahoo.com")
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Find(StrString,URL)
    Dim Title,ie,objRegex,Matches,Data
    Title = "Find a String in a webpage"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Navigate(URL) 
    ie.Visible = false 'run ie in the background
    DO WHILE ie.busy
        wscript.sleep 100
    LOOP
    Data = ie.document.documentElement.innertext
    ie.quit()
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set objRegex = new RegExp
    objRegex.Pattern = StrString
    objRegex.Global = True
    objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "We found this word : " & qq(StrString) &" : "& Matches.Count & " times "& vbCrLf &_
        "in " & qq(URL),vbInformation,Title
    End If
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function qq(strIn)
    qq = Chr(34) & strIn & Chr(34)
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Or with `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` Object :

```
Option Explicit
Call Find("StackOverflow","https://stackoverflow.com")
Call Find("google","https://www.google.com")
Call Find("Hackoo","https://pastebin.com/u/hackoo")
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Find(StrString,URL)
    Dim Title,HTTP_Request,objRegex,Matches,Data
    Title = "Find a String in a webpage"
    Set HTTP_Request = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    HTTP_Request.Open "GET", URL, False
    HTTP_Request.send()
    Data = HTTP_Request.responseText
    Set objRegex = new RegExp
    objRegex.Pattern = StrString
    objRegex.Global = True
    objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "We found this word : " & qq(StrString) &" : "& Matches.Count & " times "& vbCrLf &_
        "in " & qq(URL),vbInformation,Title
    End If
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function qq(strIn)
    qq = Chr(34) & strIn & Chr(34)
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```